# How to Make C# Source Generators Create Files in Two Projects Simultaneously?

Tags: c#, maui, roslyn

I have 3 projects.

Project 1: Simple Dotnet MAUI App.

Project 2: A Class Library which acts as a custom NuGet Package which does some work. Lets say reads few key value pairs from a location and puts it in a public dict and makes it accessible.

Project 3: A C# SourceGenerator. It has 2 SourceGenerator.
1) Creates a C# file from a xml file with property names in sync with keys in the xml file.
2) Creates a xml file(independent of the previous point) and puts in a location.

Now,

Project 1, has a link to Project 2 using the NuGet Package, or local reference for testing.

Project 2, has a link to Project 3, i.e. the SourceGenerator Project using ProjectReference.

The problem:
I have a xml file in Project 1, lets say File1.xml, set as c# additional analyzer files
I want Project 3(Source Generators) to Read the File1.xml file and do the following:

- 1 Source Generator: Read xml file and create a c# file and put it in Project 2 (which has a reference from Project 2 to project 3)
- 2 Source Generator: Read xml file and creates a copy of xml file File2.xml and puts it in Project 1.

I am unable to get this to work.

I have all code for SourceGenerators functionality, A Class Library which acts as a custom NuGet Package which does some work. Lets say reads few key value pairs from a location and puts it in a public dict and makes it accessible a Simple MAUI app as well.
If I have a .xml file in Project 2 (class lib which calls SourceGenerator/Project 3 directly) instead of Project 1, it creates both file correctly but in Project 2.

Cant get it to work from .xml in Project 1 and adding files to both Projects.

1 thing I am considering is:
Have both Project 1 and Project 2 refer to Project 3. And have something like this

```cs
        if (IsProject1(context))
        {
            // Run Source Generator 1 for Project 1
            context.AddGeneratorRunForAllGeneratedFiles(SourceGenerator1);
        }
        else if (IsProject2(context))
        {
            // Run Source Generator 2 for Project 2
            context.AddGeneratorRunForAllGeneratedFiles(SourceGenerator2);
        }

        private bool IsProject1(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            // Implement logic to determine if the current project is Project 1
            // You can check project references or other project-specific attributes

            // For example, you can check the project's assembly name
            return context.Compilation.AssemblyName == "Project1";
        }

        private bool IsProject2(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            // Implement logic to determine if the current project is Project 2
            // You can check project references or other project-specific attributes

            // For example, you can check the project's assembly name
            return context.Compilation.AssemblyName == "Project2";
        }
```